# Xcode 4 missing drop down lists in Build Settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I'm using Xcode 4 and in Build Settings all drop down lists have gone away.

Instead of the drop down lists, I have text boxes.

See this image, for example:

[image]

I'm totally puzzled: how can I enable drop down lists again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Xcode:

Editor -> Show Values

It just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some random ideas:

1. Try deleting / then re-set the setting.
2. Maybe your xcode project file `.xcodeproj` is dirty.
   You should give a look at its xml file > `xxxxxx.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
3. You did something bad to your Xcode install, reinstall/upgrade :)
4. Check your Xcode settings/preferences/garbage files (move / delete to reset...) which you can find there :

   - `~/Library/Preferences/` > `com.apple.Xcode.plist` & `com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
   - `~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode`
   - `~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode/`
   - `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/`

Comment: I reinstalled Xcode 4 after uninstalling it with sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all and I also deleted xcuserdata and project.xcworkspace, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Added a 4th idea. If it is not Xcode install nor your project the culprit, then it might be your preferences files...

Comment: Deleting the preferences might work, but luckily there is a simpler solution by Terry Wilcox above

Answer (score 0):

Wow, spent the best part of a few days trying to resolve this exact issue. Thanks.

[Xcode5 "No matching provisioning profiles found issue" (but good at xcode4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475964/xcode5-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-issue-but-good-at-xcode4/22876400#22876400)