# Xcode5 "No matching provisioning profiles found issue" (but good at xcode4)

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Everything is OK on Xcode4.6. When I try to use Xcode5 dp6 to run app on devices. I got an error of "No matching provisioning profiles found issue". How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have to ask. Have you tried clicking the "Fix Issue" button?

Comment: yes, i have tried on that, but not work

Comment: "Fix issue" just got stuck in a loop of supposedly fixing it for me.  Regenerating certificates manually from the site and ensuring provisioning profile correctly set on the target (see images below) actually fixed it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Don't forget to change profile in Provision Profile sections:
[image]

Ideally you should see `Automatic` in `Code Signing Identity` after you choose provision profile you need. If you don't see any option that's mean you don't have private key for current provision profile.

Comment: Thanks Danil.
I solved this problem with your answer.

Comment: @TomFishman Why Xcode doesn't require it? If you'd like to test your app on device you need provision profile with private key.

Comment: Xcode can handle it automatically now. We don't set it up any more.

Comment: @TomFishman Do you mean "Fix issue" button which dosen't helps actually because sometimes you don't have provision for your bindle id? And how Xcode can get private key for your provision if you don't have it? I know you can generate a new private key in Xcode automaticaly but it's a really bad practice if you are working in team. So it's still an issue and a lot of developers work prefering manual settings

Answer (score 50):

What really confused me was that there are two different sets of build settings:
1) for the Project
2) for the Target

In the sidebar (top left) there is a blue icon that represents your project. Click that:
[image]

Then in the main panel to the right, in the top bar, just to the left of the word, "General," there is a small icon of your Project. Click that, and now select the Target in the pop-up menu that appears:

[image: the Target selection]

Once you've selected the Target, now the build settings for the target can be changed. They are different than the ones for the Project itself... weird! I'm not sure why there are build settings for the Project as a whole, that are different from the Target, since the Target's settings are what gets used during building. So why even have settings for the Project? Not sure.

But that's how you change them. This solved the issue for me: go into the Target (not the Project!) under **Code Signing > Provisioning Profile >** and change the settings to the proper profile. For a long time I was just changing them in the Project only, since I didn't know I was supposed to select the Target, and I kept having this issue. This fixes it!

Comment: This was exactly it for me; it's extremely confusing UI.  If you could edit your screenshot to put a big red circle around the correct "Angel of View" piece, it might help others.  I spent a few minutes re-reading and clicking.  The project and target names are only shown about six times on the screen.  ;)

Comment: Done. I added the circles. I agree, this aspect of XCode's UI is really confusing. Hence trying to help.

Comment: Thanks a million times!! I wasted a couple of hours on this in the new XCode and was pulling my hair out. The Target setting are hidden in this new UI and I hate it! I wish Apple stops constantly fiddling with XCode ui and where things are.

Comment: Thumbs up!! I always missed the Target... Apple should change Target settings for us automatically when we change the Project settings. I remembered MSFT does that for VS products

Comment: I read through this and everything in my target was already correctly set up. What fixed it was to go to the project and change the IDs there. Bizarre. I think they need to change the submit process.

Comment: And I'm *still* getting upvotes on this... come on, Apple :D

Answer (score 7):

Setting your provisioning profile moved. It confounded me for a while until I found it also.

1. Select your project file (to open target)
2. Click on the "Build Settings" tab
3. Scroll down to "Code Signing" and see the new "Provisioning Profile" section there.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

OK - all answers provided above are correct to some extend, but did not resolve this issue for me. I'm using Xcode5.

There are lots of threads around this general error but from what I read this is a bug in Xcode dating back to 3.x versions that can randomly create conflicts with your Keychain.

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Open Xcode -> preferences -> Accounts: delete your developer account
2. Open Keychain: Select Keys, delete all iOS keys; Select My Certificates, delete all iPhone certificates
3. Navigate to '/Users//Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles', delete all files (this is where Xcode stores mobile profiles)
4. Open Xcode -> preferences -> Accounts: re-add your developer account
5. Navigate to Project properties, Target, General Tab and you should see the following [image]
6. Click 'Revoke and Request' (I tried this, it may take a few min) or 'Import Developer Profile' (or download from Apple developer portal and import this way, should be faster..)
7. FINALLY: you can go over to Build Settings and set 'Provisioning Profile' and 'Signing Settings' as described by everyone here..

Doing this and only this resolved this error for me.

Comment: You should be very careful doing this, you could lose private keys if you do this incorrectly.

Comment: .. well the alternative is not being able to run your project at all :)

Comment: you should avoid to do it especially if you are working in team

Comment: you're a hero! Thanks for this advice. This fixed the problem for me!

Comment: This worked for me. I agree with @TomFishman - step 2 wasn't necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution that worked for me:

In XCode5,  double-click on your app's target. This brings up the Info pane for the target. In the "Build Settings" section, check the "code signing" section for any old profiles and replace with the correct one.  update the value of "code signing identity" and "provisioning profile"

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially after generating a new certificate or starting to use a new code signing identity, there seems to be no other way to fix this, other than doing some cleaning the .pbxproj file. This is probably a bug that will be fixed, so if you are reading this long after this post, maybe you should try some other solution.

There is an excellent post about this in the pixeldock blog:
http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found/

In short, mostly quoting from that article, you need to:

1. Make sure you have fetched all your remote iTunes Connect certificates in xcode5 from Preferences, Accounts, (select your account), View Details, press refresh button. (Normally, I answer no when xcode asks if I want to create certficate signing requests, it's not necessary when you only want to download/refresh your certificates)
2. Close Xcode
3. Right click on your project’s .xcodeproj bundle to show it’s contents.
4. Open the .pbxproj file in a text editor of your choice (make a backup copy first if you feel paranoid)
5. Find all lines in that file that include the word PROVISIONING_PROFILE and delete them.
6. Open Xcode
7. Enter your target and select the provisioning profile that you want to use.
8. Build your project

Good luck!

Comment: Removing just the line with PROVISIONING_PROFILE that contained the offending profile ID fixed my problem.  Sometimes some old-fashioned text editing is best.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks VM.  (Running Xcode 6.1.1, iOS SDK 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

In xcode5 from Preferences, Accounts, (select your account), View Details, press refresh button. then select Provision Profile in build settings.

Comment: I had changed my password with developer.apple.com but not within xcode so it couldn't properly update my provisioning profiles. Make sure the saved password in xcode is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "Fix Issue" button triggers a spinner for about 20 seconds and fixes nothing.

This works for me (iOS 7 iPhone 5, Xcode 5):

Xcode > Window > Organizer > Devices

Find the connected device(with a green dot) on the left pane.
Select "Provisioning Profiles" 
On the right pane, there is a line with warning.
Delete this line.

Now go back to click the "Fix Issue" button and everything is fine - the app runs in the device as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 targets in my project, Free and Paid.
My mistake was i was looking at my free target while trying to build the paid target, a stupid mistake but possible someone out there might learn from this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same question as you you can click here ：

> [About the question in xcode5 "no matching provisioning profiles found"](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s227/sh/956fd34d-c9fe-413d-be39-2bae0c1e6c58/86eb27e703cc7477668c291980a6793c)

（About xcode5 的no matching provisioning profiles found  ）

When I was fitting with iOS7，I get the warning like this：no matching provisioning profiles found.
the reason may be that your project is in other group.

Do like this：find the file named ***.xcodeproj in your protect，show the content of it.

You will see three files：

1. project.pbxproj
2. project.xcworkspace
3. xcuserdata

open the first, search the uuid and delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

All of drop down lists disappeared in Build Settings after running the Fix Issue in Xcode 5. Spent several days trying to figure out what was wrong with my provisioning profiles and code signing. Found a link [Xcode 4 missing drop down lists in Build Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807650/xcode-4-missing-drop-down-lists-in-build-settings) and sure enough I needed to re-enabled "Show Values" under the Editor menu. Hopefully this helps anyone else in this predicament.

Also, I had to clear my derived data, clean the solution and quit and reopen Xcode into for the code signing identities to correctly appear. My distribution provisioning profiles where showing up as signed by my developer certificate which was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today, with XCode 6.1

What I found was that, no matter what I tried, I couldn't get XCode to stop complaining about this Provisioning Profile with a GUID as its name.

The solution was to search for this GUID in the .**pbxproj** file, which lives within the XCode .**xcodeproj** folder.

Just find the line containing your GUID:

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "A9234343-.....34"
```

and change it to:

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ""
```

One other thing to check:  Your XCode PROJECT settings contain your Provisioning Profile & Code Signing settings, but, there is a *second set* under your project's "TARGETS" tab.

So, if XCode is complaining about a Provisioning Profile which isn't the one quoted in your project settings, then go have have a look at the settings shown under "TARGETS" in your XCode project.

(I wish someone had given me this advice, 4 painful hours ago..)

Comment: I deleted all the provisioning_profile statements. When I tried to build it, it offered the "Fix" option, but this time it worked.