# Third party Xcode project, no matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I received a complete Xcode project from another developer. I can run the app in the simulator but I get the "No matching provisioning profiles found" error message when trying to compile it to my iOS device.

How can I get this to compile to my device? Changing the provisioning profile to my own under build settings doesn't work.

Comment: You need to have an active IOS developer account to put apps on devices. If use your own, then you have to generate certificates/bundle-id/provisioning profiles. If you share the same account with someone else, they should export their profiles from xcode and provide them to you.

Comment: here is linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475964/xcode5-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-issue-but-good-at-xcode4/19264387#19264387

Comment: Thanks Danil, that answer did solve my problem after all. I had seen that answer before posting my own question, but because I had already played around with the values I couldn't get it to run. Works now though

Answer (score 0):

This error mean your provisioning profile is wrong. Check your provisioning profile installed and certificate are right. Check if your device is register for this provisioning profile too maybe you didnt add it to your provisioning profile