# Xcode 7: "No matching provisioning profiles found"

Tags: ios, xcode, export, provisioning-profile

I've changed the App ID and created a new provisioning profile for it. The new bundle ID and provisioning profile seem to be correctly set in the target's settings, and I get no warning when archiving it. But when I want to export the archive, Xcode shows me a dialog saying:

> No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/MyApp.app"

And below it says that:

> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups

What I'm missing to check/change?

Thanks

**EDIT:** In the warning dialog I'm also shown the buttons "Visit Member Center" and "Import Developer Profile". Do I need to set a developer profile if I just want to export a distribution binary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode6 error: "No matching provisioning profiles found for application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006773/xcode6-error-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-application)

Comment: May be your certificate is outdated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28006826/742298

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Member Center** and then "**Certificates, identifier and profiles**" then create a new developer profile. Download and double click on profile then clean you app. and run.

if not solve. see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8

Comment: It is solved the problem but, usually facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

What resolved the issue was manually setting `Provisioning Profile` for `Debug` and `Release` to the appropriate values, as opposed to choosing `Automatic` (i.e., set values to your development and distribution provisioning profiles). Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19264387/144088).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Xcode 7.2:

Select your target, then the "General" tab. In the "Identity" section there was a warning that no provisioning profiles were found, and a button that said "Fix issue." I pressed it, and it fixed the issue.

In my case I was missing the automatically generated provisioning profiles because I had changed the bundle ID in an existing project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a provisioning profile with an explicit app Bundle ID rather than a Wildcard one.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 8 ( As I tried it on 8 and it worked)
First of all clean the project
Xcode-->Product-->Clean
Select simulator as Generic IOS Device
Then again click on product --> Archive 
After the archive is made xcode automatically takes you to orgaiser or else you can click on windows--> organiser.
here you can see all the archive you have made in past.
Now, the main part:
Select an archive you want to export.
Click on export. Its on right side under the "upload to store Button"
When You click it ask to select 1 out of 4 options, select--> Save for Development Deployment (4th option)
After This it fetch the account, Make sure you select the account by which you have made provisional profile or signing certificate.
Thats it, it will start preparing your IPA.
It ask to export your IPA to the preferred location & makes a folder their.

In my case it helped.
No other 3 option gave me same error about provisioning profile but not the 4th one.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not userful by regenerating your Provisioning profile ,you can try to go to **TARGETS**/**Build Settings**/**Packing**/**Product Bundle identifier**,Maybe you forget change the bundle identifier.